# Android: How to retrieve album_art for each album using album_id?

Tags: android, albumart

```
public Bitmap getAlbumart(Long album_id) 
   {
        Bitmap bm = null;
        try 
        {
            final Uri sArtworkUri = Uri
                .parse("content://media/external/audio/albumart");

            Uri uri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(sArtworkUri, album_id);

            ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r"); //Error

            if (pfd != null) 
            {
                FileDescriptor fd = pfd.getFileDescriptor();
                bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fd);
            }
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
    return bm;
}
```

Comment: What's the error?  Please include the logcat if it's relevant.

Comment: After reading the..ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = context.getContentResolver()
                .openFileDescriptor(uri, "r");...Control jumps to exception everytime..

Comment: What's the exception?

Comment: I found out the solution using Picasso library to display the album. thank you.